# set delete button in UITableview through an action of bar button in navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am developing an app which contains a table view. I want to appear the default delete button  of table view (similar to swipe on delete) while tapping a right bar button in the navigation. IS it possible to do so ?

Comment: Yes, in general it's possible, but we'll be able to help you with your particular situation better if you [let us know what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, I have already done swipe on delete by using the following tableview delegate function. - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the delete indicators of all cells to appear by calling

```
[myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

from your button's handler. If you want the indicator to appear only on the currently selected cell, you can do this:

```
NSIndexPath selection = [myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [myTableView.dataSource tableView:myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selection];
[selectedCell setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```